# combine array of objects by key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to combine/merge 2 array of objects by key in my case id.

**Objective:**

1. I am expecting a results where I would have array containing all objects with ids 1,2,3,4 as per example
2. Order of merging should not affect number of objects in result for example `combine(arr1,arr2)`  or `combine(arr2,arr1)` should have array with same number of objects
3. Order of merging can only affect resulting object for example in case of `combine(arr1,arr2)`  arr2 key,values pair can override arr1 key,values just like deep jquery extend $.extend( true, arr1ObJ,arr2ObJ );

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/u2c05nyj/

**Sample Data:**

```
var arr1 = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "fred",
  title: "boss"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "jim",
  title: "nobody"
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "bob",
  title: "dancer"
}];
var arr2 = [{
  id: 1,
  wage: "300",
  rate: "day"
}, {
  id: 2,
  wage: "10",
  rate: "hour"
}, {
  id: 4,
  wage: "500",
  rate: "week"
}];
var Result = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "fred",
  "title": "boss",
  "wage": "300",
  "rate": "day"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "jim",
  "title": "nobody",
  "wage": "10",
  "rate": "hour"
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "bob",
  title: "dancer" 
}, {
  id: 4,
  wage: "500",
  rate: "week"
}];
```

Comment: why you have made it complex. you should use `$.extend`

Comment: @Parth  ```$.extend(true,arr1,arr2)``` skips key with id 3 . see here https://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/u2c05nyj/2/

Comment: may this help you http://underscorejs.org/#union

Comment: underscore i cant use

Comment: `$.extend` won't work because it will think object with `id: 3` should be overwritten by object with `id: 4`

Comment: @django why does the result have a wage and rate for `id: 3`?

Comment: from `Result` - bob has no associated data in `arr2`, how do we derive his wage as 300? Also, id4 does not have an entry in `arr1` and it needs to be in part of the `Result`. Asking because it sounds weird to include this 'phantom' employee's wage record.

Comment: @Samuel ,@Michael 
 Sorry fixed result above. bob has only id,name ,title.
And yes id 4 must be part of result and so as id 3 since I want to deep merge array of objects based on id key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something along the lines of this:

```
function combineArrays(arr1, arr2, keyFunc) {
    var combined = [],
        keys1 = arr1.map(keyFunc),
        keys2 = arr2.map(keyFunc),
        pos1 = keys1.map(function (id) {
            return keys2.indexOf(id);
        }),
        pos2 = keys2.map(function (id) {
            return keys1.indexOf(id);
        });

    arr1.forEach(function (item, i) {
        combined.push( $.extend(item, arr2[pos1[i]]) );
    });
    arr2.forEach(function (item, i) {
        if (pos2[i] === -1) combined.push( item );
    });
    return combined;    
}
```

used as

```
var combine = combineArrays(arr1, arr2, function (item) {
    return item.id;
});
```

```js
var arr1 = [
    { id: 1, name: 'fred', title: 'boss' },
    { id: 2, name: 'jim', title: 'nobody' },
    { id: 3, name: 'bob', title: 'dancer' }
];
var arr2 = [
    { id: 1, wage: '300', rate: 'day' },
    { id: 2, wage: '10', rate: 'hour' },
    { id: 4, wage: '500', rate: 'week' }
];

function combineArrays(arr1, arr2, keyFunc) {
    var combined = [],
        keys1 = arr1.map(keyFunc),
        keys2 = arr2.map(keyFunc),
        pos1 = keys1.map(function (id) {
            return keys2.indexOf(id);
        }),
        pos2 = keys2.map(function (id) {
            return keys1.indexOf(id);
        });

    arr1.forEach(function (item, i) {
        combined.push( $.extend(item, arr2[pos1[i]]) );
    });
    arr2.forEach(function (item, i) {
        if (pos2[i] === -1) combined.push( item );
    });
    return combined;
}

var combine = combineArrays(arr1, arr2, function (item) {
    return item.id;
});

output(combine);



//
//
//
/* pretty Print */
function output(inp) {
    var str = JSON.stringify(inp, undefined, 4);
    $('body').append($('<pre/>').html(str));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It works perfectly. compact code. But I am assuming Michael`s answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38672075/2139859 above has only 2 loops ,so it will be more performant ?  Please suggest performance wise

Comment: Performance is fixed by comparing and analyzing, not by making assumptions. Generally speaking, yes, `forEach()` is more work than a `for` loop. But will it matter for your use case? How many array elements do you typically have? Is that section of code under a lot of stress? I wrote *"along the lines of this"* to imply that you are free to make modifications. Replacing `forEach()` does not even increase the line count, go ahead and do it if you find that it makes a difference.

Comment: Mine actually has 3 loops and should be O(nm + np) if I remember my stuff right.  n and m are the sizes of the arrays, p would be the number of properties an object of the array has.  If p is always 2 or constant, then it's simply O(nm).  If the arrays are always the same length, it's O(n^2).  If compactness is important, mine has a lot of unnecessary braces.  It's only about 15 lines of code.  I wouldn't worry too much about performance unless you're going to run on large input sets.  In that case, mine would definitely be a better option.

Comment: @Michael Thankx for the input.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution.  It basically goes through each element of arr2 and checks to see if there's an element with a matching ID arr1.  If so, it updates the matching element in arr1 with arr2's values.  If there is no match, it simply pushes the element in arr2 onto arr1.

```
var arr1 = [{id: 1,name: 'fred',title: 'boss'}, 
            {id: 2,name: 'jim',title: 'nobody'}, 
            {id: 3,name: 'bob',title: 'dancer'}];

var arr2 = [{id: 1,wage: '300',rate: 'day'}, 
            {id: 2,wage: '10',rate:'hour'},
            {id: 4,wage: '500',rate: 'week'}];

function combineArrays(arr1, arr2) {
  for(var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    // check if current object exists in arr1
    var idIndex = hasID(arr2[i]['id'], arr1);
    if(idIndex >= 0){
      //update
      for(var key in arr2[i]){
        arr1[idIndex][key] = arr2[i][key];
      }
    } else {
      //insert
      arr1.push(arr2[i]);
    }
  }

  return arr1;
}

//Returns position in array that ID exists
function hasID(id, arr) {
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
    if(arr[i]['id'] === id)
    {
      return i;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}

var combine = combineArrays(arr1, arr2);
output(combine);

/* pretty Print */
function output(inp) {
  var str = JSON.stringify(inp, undefined, 4);
  $('body').append($('<pre/>').html(str));
}
```

```js
var arr1 = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'fred',
  title: 'boss'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'jim',
  title: 'nobody'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'bob',
  title: 'dancer'
}];

var arr2 = [{
  id: 1,
  wage: '300',
  rate: 'day'
}, {
  id: 2,
  wage: '10',
  rate: 'hour'
}, {
  id: 4,
  wage: '500',
  rate: 'week'
}];

function combineArrays(arr1, arr2) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    var idIndex = hasID(arr2[i]['id'], arr1);
    if (idIndex >= 0) {
      for (var key in arr2[i]) {
        arr1[idIndex][key] = arr2[i][key];
      }
    } else {
      arr1.push(arr2[i]);
    }
  }

  return arr1;
}

function hasID(id, arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i]['id'] === id) {
      return i;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}

var combine = combineArrays(arr1, arr2);
output(combine);

/* pretty Print */
function output(inp) {
  var str = JSON.stringify(inp, undefined, 4);
  $('body').append($('<pre/>').html(str));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```